# find the index of a boolean array whose values are true

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, boolean

I am wondering whats the best way to find all the indices of a `Boolean` array, of which the values are `True`. For example, an array of `bool` values,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([True, False, True, False, True])
true_list = A[A == True].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will do it easily:

```
np.where(A)
```

Or:

```
A.nonzero()
```

Comment: `true_list, = np.where(A)` is what I was going to go for, but yeah :)

Comment: Note, in both cases above, the result is a tuple of numpy arrays, one for each dimension of A. In this case the result would be: `(array([0, 2, 4]),)`. You'll have to do `np.where(A)[0]` to get `array([0, 2, 4])`

Comment: np.where can be used for other array_like objects like list & not just numpy arrays.